# Why I cannot find the memory acclocated on Heap using HeapMemView?

Tags: c++, windows, memory

i am trying to view the heap memory of a C++ code.

I am working on Windows currently and using HeapMemView.

I use the code below, trying to allocate some memory on the heap and try to 
find them out using HeapMemView...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char * a = new char[5000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = 'a';
    }

    cout << a;

    int b = 0;
    cin >> b;

    return 0;
}
```

I will let the code stop at **cin >> b** and start HeapMemView to view the heap content.

I export all the segments of heap memory HeapMemView generated and cat them into one hex file, reading them in Sublime Text 2...

My question is I cannot find a long sequence of "aaaaaaaaa..." as well as "61616161616161".....

Am I doing the stuff wrong...?

And Could anyone tell me is there a similiar tool like HeapMemView on Linux...?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I see it.  Use the correct bitness for the utility, it doesn't handle 32-bit processes on 64-bit Windows gracefully.  Look for a block that's 5056 bytes in the Debug build.

Comment: Hi Hans, thank you and right after I asdked this question, I find the solution. I initially use a 64 bit HeapMemView on my 64bit Windows using 32 bit g++... I use a 32 bit HeapMemView and it works fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially use a 64 bit HeapMemView on my 64bit Windows using 32 bit g++...

I use a 32 bit HeapMemView and it works fine